# Modify the 'forgot password' email template

Tags: members, email, login, password, forgot-password

When a user fills a 'forgot password' form, he or she receives an email like this:

```
username,

To reset your password, please go to the following page:

[link to reset password]

Your password will be automatically reset, and a new password will be
emailed to you.

If you do not wish to reset your password, ignore this message. It will
expire in 24 hours.
```

Works well for me, except my site is in french. Where is this template or where can I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the copy in the [**Message Pages**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/message_pages/index.html#email-notification-templates) area of the Control Panel... specifically edit the "Password Reset Notification" template.

**Control Panel Location:** Design ‣ Message Pages